# Sales Price Updating Every Other Time

Tags: acumatica

I have extended the SOOrderEntry graph and added the following code in order to update another line on the same sales order that is related to the current line that is being updated:

```
protected virtual void SOLine_RowUpdating(PXCache cache, PXRowUpdatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewRow == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    SOLine soLine = (SOLine)e.NewRow;

    SOLine relatedLine = Base.Transactions.Search<SOLine.inventoryID> 
    (456);

    if (relatedLine != null)
    {
           relatedLine.Qty = soLine.Qty;
           relatedLine.CuryUnitPrice = 24.20;

           Base.Transactions.Update(relatedLine);
           Base.Transactions.View.RequestRefresh();
    }
}
```

When I try to test this by updating the Qty on the current line, the Unit Price on the related line only updates every other time that I update the Qty.  The related item is a Non-stock item where the current item is a Stock Item.

I'm doing this in a Sales Demo environment on 18.102.0048

I tried this but, now the Extended Price is always 0.00:

```
protected virtual void SOLine_RowUpdating(PXCache cache, PXRowUpdatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewRow == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    SOLine soLine = (SOLine)e.NewRow;

    SOLine relatedLine = Base.Transactions.Search<SOLine.inventoryID> 
(456);

    if (relatedLine != null)
    {
       SOLine oldRelatedLine = PXCache<SOLine>.CreateCopy(relatedLine);
       relatedLine.Qty = soLine.Qty;
       relatedLine.CuryUnitPrice = 24.20;

       Base.Transactions.Cache.RaiseRowUpdated(relatedLine, oldRelatedLine);

       Base.Transactions.Update(relatedLine);
       Base.Transactions.View.RequestRefresh();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a field calculated value depends on another field value it's sometimes required to trigger events for the value to be recalculated.

In some cases it only requires firing the event for the field that you modified. Assigning values using the C# assignment operator (=) or the SetValue method will not trigger the events handler, SetValueExt method will:

```
// Doesn't trigger events
relatedLine.Qty = soLine.Qty;
cache.SetValue<SOLine.qty>(relatedLine, soLine.Qty);

// This will trigger events
cache.SetValueExt<SOLine.qty>(relatedLine, soLine.Qty);
```

There are some cases where you need to fire events for the whole row too. You can use the RaiseXxxYyy methods to do that. I used Current in the example but you might have to adapt it if Current is not the row being modified:

```
SOLine oldRowCopy = PXCache<SOLine>.CreateCopy(Base.Transactions.Current);
Base.Transactions.Current.Qty = soLine.Qty;
Base.Transactions.Cache.RaiseRowUpdated(Base.Transactions.Current, oldRowCopy);
```

**EDIT**:

Looking at updated question, it might not make much of a difference but I suggest you switch the order of these 2 lines:

```
   Base.Transactions.Cache.RaiseRowUpdated(relatedLine, oldRelatedLine);
   Base.Transactions.Update(relatedLine);
```

Like this:

```
// You want the value in Cache to be updated
Base.Transactions.Update(relatedLine);

// After Cache value is set you want to raise the events
Base.Transactions.Cache.RaiseRowUpdated(relatedLine, oldRelatedLine);
```

Comment: When it does refresh every other time, it's because you are doing some manipulations on screen (changing fields in UI, changing control Focus) that re-trigger the events leading to recalculation of the fields.

Comment: yeah, that's exactly what I'm doing - hitting Enter or Tab after modifying the Qty and the focus moves to the next field on the line.

Comment: Try calling RaiseRowUpdated on the 'relatedLine' object after setting 'relatedLine.Qty'. I think that should do it.

Comment: ok, I tried the RaiseRowUpdated and it does keep the Unit Price now but, the extended price is always 0.00.  Thanks for the info. It's really helpful, btw.

Comment: ok I take it that it was an improvement. More fiddling around triggering events could be required for CuryExtPrice field. Sales Order Entry is peculiar in that it has a lot of these inter-linked fields. I'll take a more in-depth look at it on Monday. What you can try is manually set ExtPrice, formula is quite simple orderQty * curyUnitPrice [PXFormula(typeof(Mult<SOLine.orderQty, SOLine.curyUnitPrice>))] and raise the FieldDefaulting event of the curyExtPrice which should re-calculate the formula using Base.Transactions.Cache.RaiseFieldDefaulting<SOLine.curyExtPrice>(relatedLine, out newValue)

Comment: Yes, adding the RaiseRowUpdated() was an improvement but, still not getting an extended price.  I've tried adding the RaiseFieldUpdated call for both the orderQty and the curyUnitPrice but, that causes the Unit Price to become 0.00 again.  Changing the order in which the Update() and RaiseRowUpdated() is called does make a difference.  If I call Update() first, the Unit Price is wiped out again.  It's a real pickle.

Comment: Sorry, I tried the RaiseFieldUpdated and RaiseFieldDefaulting but, to no avail.  I'm going to keep trying and erroring.  :)

Comment: Nothing happens when you set ExtPrice manually using orderQty * curyUnitPrice ?

Comment: True, nothing happened when I set the curyExtPrice manually.  I even checked in the RowUpdated() event to be sure that the value was still correct.  However, I just tried setting the value by using the SetValueExt<>() and we're in business.  So, the combination of SetValueExt<>() and RaiseRowUpdated() seems to have done the trick.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to HB_ACUMATICA, here's the code that resolved this:

```
protected virtual void SOLine_RowUpdating(PXCache cache, PXRowUpdatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewRow == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    SOLine soLine = (SOLine)e.NewRow;

    SOLine relatedLine = Base.Transactions.Search<SOLine.inventoryID>(456);

    if (relatedLine != null)
    {
       SOLine oldRelatedLine = PXCache<SOLine>.CreateCopy(relatedLine);
       relatedLine.Qty = soLine.Qty;
       relatedLine.CuryUnitPrice = 24.20;

       object outPrice = 0.01;
       outPrice = (relatedLine.CuryUnitPrice * relatedLine.Qty);
       cache.SetValueExt<SOLine.curyExtPrice>(relatedLine, outPrice);

       Base.Transactions.Cache.RaiseRowUpdated(relatedLine, oldRelatedLine);

       Base.Transactions.Update(relatedLine);

       Base.Transactions.View.RequestRefresh();
    }
}
```