# Insert SO line after the user confirms it in a dialog box

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to add a line in the Transactions grid after the Customer is entered, but only if the user accepts it - a dialog box is shown for this confirmation.

I have reduced the logic to a very simple SOLine insertion.

With this code, the result is successful:

```
    protected virtual void SOOrder_RowUpdated(PXCache sender, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        SOOrder record = (SOOrder)e.Row;

        if (!sender.ObjectsEqual<SOOrder.customerID>(e.Row, e.OldRow)
                && record.CustomerID != null)
        {
            SOLine sOLineNewRow = new SOLine();
            sOLineNewRow = this.Base.Transactions.Insert(sOLineNewRow);
            SOLineExt sOLineExtRow = PXCache<SOLine>.GetExtension<SOLineExt>(sOLineNewRow);

            sOLineNewRow.InventoryID = 311;
            this.Base.Transactions.Update(sOLineNewRow);

            sOLineNewRow.OrderQty = (decimal)7;
            this.Base.Transactions.Update(sOLineNewRow);


            sOLineNewRow.CuryUnitPrice = (decimal)8;
            this.Base.Transactions.Update(sOLineNewRow);
        }
    }
```

However, when I include the dialog box with the Ask() method, the logic is not executed. After debugging, I noticed that the logic within the if operator is not even being accessed.

```
    protected virtual void SOOrder_RowUpdated(PXCache sender, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        SOOrder record = (SOOrder)e.Row;

        if (!sender.ObjectsEqual<SOOrder.customerID>(e.Row, e.OldRow)
                && record.CustomerID != null)
        {
            if (this.Base.Document.Ask("Confirmation",
                                                        "The selected customer will have the default line. Do you want to insert it?",
                                                        MessageButtons.YesNo,
                                                        MessageIcon.Question) == WebDialogResult.Yes)
            {
                SOLine sOLineNewRow = new SOLine();
                sOLineNewRow = this.Base.Transactions.Insert(sOLineNewRow);
                SOLineExt sOLineExtRow = PXCache<SOLine>.GetExtension<SOLineExt>(sOLineNewRow);

                sOLineNewRow.InventoryID = 311;
                this.Base.Transactions.Update(sOLineNewRow);

                sOLineNewRow.OrderQty = (decimal)7;
                this.Base.Transactions.Update(sOLineNewRow);


                sOLineNewRow.CuryUnitPrice = (decimal)8;
                this.Base.Transactions.Update(sOLineNewRow);
            }
        }

    }
```

Does anyone know why this might be occurring?

**UPDATED QUESTION**

I replicated the logic in an Action and the result is successful there:

```
public PXAction<SOOrder> ChangeAmount;
       [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Action Test", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
       [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
       public virtual void changeAmount()
       {
           PXTrace.WriteInformation("BeforeAskAction");

           if (this.Base.Document.Ask("Confirmation",
                                                       "The selected customer will have the default line. Do you want to insert it?",
                                                       MessageButtons.YesNo,
                                                       MessageIcon.Question) == WebDialogResult.Yes)
           {
               PXTrace.WriteInformation("AfterAskAction");

               SOLine sOLineNewRow = new SOLine();
               sOLineNewRow = this.Base.Transactions.Insert(sOLineNewRow);

               sOLineNewRow.InventoryID = 311;
               this.Base.Transactions.Update(sOLineNewRow);

               sOLineNewRow.OrderQty = (decimal)7;
               this.Base.Transactions.Update(sOLineNewRow);

               sOLineNewRow.CuryUnitPrice = (decimal)8;
               this.Base.Transactions.Update(sOLineNewRow);
           }
       }
```

Both "BeforeAskAction" and "AfterAskAction" traces were logged.

In my original scenario with the Event Handler, only the "Before" trace is entered.

I tested with the following datamembers:
- Document
- CurrentDocument
- Transactions
- A dummy DM that I created with the SOLine DAC.
In all of these scenarios, the result is successful in the action but fails in the event handler.

**UPDATE 2**

Initially, I had the logic in SOOrder_CustomerID_FieldUpdated.
In this event the record is getting inserted, however I could not continue using it because the CuryUnitPrice was not assigning the amount indicated in the code. It assigned the Item's default price.

I used this article as reference ([Sales Price Updating Every Other Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51564225/sales-price-updating-every-other-time)), but the result was still showing the default amount.
When RowUpdated event is used - and the Ask() method is not implemented - my CuryUnitPrice amount is assigned

Comment: If you expect that the debugger will step right from the Ask line to the body of the condition '{ }', I think that will not happen. It seems to take an additional roundtrip and it will jump inside the body of the condition asynchronously. That is on first call of the method it will appear to step right through skipping the body, later on it will jump back asynchronously to execute the body after the user dismisses the dialog. You could use PXTrace instead of the debugger to confirm it does never enter.

Comment: @HB_ACUMATICA Yes. I thought it could be because it is run in a separate thread. However my logic is not executed because the SOLine is never inserted. Is there an alternative way to confirm with the user if he/she would like to have the line entered or not? Thanks

Comment: Personally I wouldn't jump to conclusion too fast. Did you try to remove all the 'if' conditions in that method and only keep the SOLine insertion? Does it insert properly in that scenario?

Comment: @HB_ACUMATICA yes. The version without the Ask() in the If operator inserted the record correctly. However, when the Ask() method is added, the line is not inserted.

Comment: The only other reason that comes to mind to explain that behavior would be related to the context when Ask is executed. Having the same logic in a Button handler could rule that out. Depending on how you set the breakpoints and hit continue I also see a slight possibility that it does enter inside but doesn't hit the breakpoint or insert the line successfully in that context. Having PXTrace.WriteInformation("Test"); and opening the trace window could rule that out.

Comment: It's great that you were able to simplify without the Ask method, going the other way around and only having the Ask method and if necessary in different context could help identify the root cause. If it really never work in any context try to use Ask method on another dataview instead of Base.Document.

Comment: @HB_ACUMATICA I updated the question. With an action the result is successful. Using different datamembers for the Ask() method is not successful in the event handler. I am open to ideas to manage this in different events, but it should occur after the user enters the customer. Unfortunately, the action will not work for us.

Comment: Maybe you could invoke the action from your event handler by calling PXAction.Press() / PXAction.PressButton(). I'm pretty sure the PressButton method will execute asynchronously so the context of the caller shouldn't matter much.

Comment: Unfortunately the outcome was the same: I added this.ChangeAmount.Press() in my event. The dialog box is shown, but the line is not inserted - similar behavior to the current situation with the event. I also tried with this.ChangeAmount.PressButton() but no luck either

Comment: @HB_ACUMATICA I updated my question with the result using CustomerID_FieldUpdated. It helps with the insertion but fails with the CuryUnitPrice amount

Comment: I think CuryUnitPrice problem is unrelated. With customization project editor check View Business Logic Source Code. In the base SOOrderEntry graph there are plenty of events that do modify the SOLine.curyUnitPrice field. All these methods and more do recompute the value of that field SOLine_RowSelected, SOLine_UOM_FieldUpdated, SOLine_Operation_FieldUpdated, SOLine_SiteID_FieldUpdated, SOLine_OrderQty_FieldUpdated, SOLine_ManualPrice_FieldUpdated, SOLine_CuryUnitPrice_FieldVerifying, SOLine_IsFree_FieldUpdated. Unless you have a very good reason I would avoid modify because it will recompute.

Comment: At least consider updating it the same way as the base SOOrderEntry graph does, either "sender.SetValueExt<SOLine.curyUnitPrice>(e.Row, row.CuryUnitPrice);" or "sender.SetDefaultExt<SOLine.curyUnitPrice>(row);" But I would really try to let the system handle Currency field by itself otherwise you might end up redefining a bunch of methods that already handle that field.

Answer (score 0):

When a framework method doesn't exhibit the expected behavior it could be because it wasn't executed in a supported context.

It is common to use the DataView [Ask()](https://help.acumatica.com/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=82d4b642-3472-0023-5ddd-5c300a903c52) method in the context of a [PXAction](https://help.acumatica.com/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=3693f848-4a5a-41fd-80e9-c0c7cfc38f1a) event handler.

If this method doesn't appear to work correctly in its current calling context, try moving it in an Action event handler.