# Updating the sales order line Unit Price

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to override the unit price in sales order entry with my own price looked up elsewhere. I do have it working with the code below but what I cannot figure out is why the line that is commented out causes a "Stack Overflow". The price does update correctly and does save to the database from session to session.

The examples I followed were provided in this post and there it's clear that the commented out line is needed : [Sales Price Updating Every Other Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51564225/sales-price-updating-every-other-time)

What it seems to be doing is the line Base.Transactions.Update(soLine); calls SOLine_RowUpdating and then you in an infinite loop.

Thanks

```
protected virtual void SOLine_RowUpdating(PXCache sender, PXRowUpdatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewRow == null)
    {
    return;
    }

    SOLine soLine = (SOLine)e.NewRow;

    decimal NewUnitPrice = 12349.56M;

    sender.SetValueExt<SOLine.curyUnitPrice>(soLine, NewUnitPrice);

    Base.Transactions.Cache.RaiseRowUpdated(soLine, soLine);

   // Base.Transactions.Update(soLine);

    Base.Transactions.View.RequestRefresh();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say that your extension is named SOOrderEntryExt ( for simplification of explanation ).
Then we have 3 Actors: 
 1. SOOrderEntry, with it's method SOLine_RowUpdating ( created by Acumatica team )
 2. SOOrderEntryExt with it's method SOLine_RowUpdating ( created by you )
 3. Acumatica cache
 4. Acumatica

Acumatica has following code:
Each time after SOLine is modified in cache, I need to execute two methods:

```
SOOrderEntry.SOLine_RowUpdating 
SOOrderEntryExt.SOLine_RowUpdating
```

Following line of code:

```
Base.Transactions.Update(soLine);
```

basically says to Acumatica, hey, soLine was updated in the cache. What Acumatica should do? Execute those two lines again:

```
SOOrderEntry.SOLine_RowUpdating 
SOOrderEntryExt.SOLine_RowUpdating
```

and again, and again, and again.
Then question arises, how to execute

```
SOOrderEntry.SOLine_RowUpdating
```

without causing eternal cycle? Next line of code is a solution:

```
Base.Transactions.Cache.RaiseRowUpdated(soLine, soLine);
```

Comment: Yuriy thank you for your clear response. That worked perfectly to save the record without going into an infinite loop. I have further problem with discounts but since it's separate topic I will make a new post.